# Extending a root of a holomorphic action

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Consider a holomorphic C*-action $\Phi$ on a smooth irreducible complex algebraic variety $X.$ If it has a square root, (that is, action $\Psi$ such that $\Phi_t=\Psi_{t^2}$) on a Zariski open $\Phi$-invariant subset $U$, is it true that one can extend this root on the whole $X?$

Comment: (should maybe insist $X$ be connected to avoid counterexamples where $U$ is not dense)

Comment: Agree! I actually added irreducible